# Rails to Angular: how to add act_as_follower

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

My app used to be a conventional Rails app, and included the **acts_as_follower** gem. Under Rails, I would use code like this:

```
    <% if current_user.following?(sentence) %>
        <%= link_to "Unfollow", unfollow_sentence_path(sentence) %>
    <% else %>
        <%= link_to "Follow", follow_sentence_path(sentence) %>
    <% end %>
```

Now that I have an Angular front-end, I am wondering how to replicate this functionality. I could use a bunch of **$http** calls, but it doesn't seem like the right way.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are probably using Rails as API backend, the optimal way to tackle Ajax calls is to wrap them on client (Angular) side with [Angular Rails Resource](https://github.com/FineLinePrototyping/angularjs-rails-resource)

Here is a simple angular rails resource service:

```js
angular.module('mymodule').factory('Book', ['railsResourceFactory', 
  function (railsResourceFactory) {
    return railsResourceFactory({
      url: '/books',
      name: 'book'
    });
  }
]);
```

In controller, you would use it like this:

```js
// Find all books matching the title
Book.query({ title: title }).then(function (results) {
  $scope.books = results;
}, function (error) {
  // do something about the error
  $scope.searching = false;
});
```